# Max Connect Time is given like 20 and Avg Connect time is giving 10 but Max and Avg Response time come like 3214 millisecond

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, kibana

While getting the load test result from jmeter in kibana dashboard. I am getting Avg Connect time and Max connect time as 10  , 20 but in Max Response time it is coming like 3256 millisecond perfectly. Kindly anyone help me why it is Connect time is coming like this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Connect Time**. JMeter measures the time it took to establish the connection, including SSL handshake. Note that connect time is not automatically subtracted from latency. In case of connection error, the metric will be equal to the time it took to face the error, for example in case of Timeout, it should be equal to connection timeout.
>
> **Latency**. JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.
>
> **Elapsed time.** JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.

So Latency is basically [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte) and Elapsed Time is [TTLB](https://community.apigee.com/questions/62413/calculate-ttlb-time-to-last-byte-and-ttfb-time-to.html)

If Connect Time is low and the delta between the Elapsed Time and the Latency is also low - then the majority of the total response time the server was busy creating the response which might indicate that it's overloaded. You need to examine your server logs and configuration, collect its health metrics using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) and eventually use a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) to determine what is the slowest part of your application which needs fixing.